# Only Retain Unique Duplicates from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT: desired output for the example given:

```
first second third fourth fifth
1     2      3     4      5
```

EDIT 2: changed count() to size()

I've come across several instances when analyzing data where I'd like to return all duplicated rows, but only one row for each duplicate. I'm trying to do so within Pandas with Python 3.

Using groupby and count I can get the output I'm looking for, but it's not intuitive. The pandas "duplicated" function doesn't return the desired output as it returns multiple rows if there are more than two duplicates.

```
    data = [[1,2,3,4,5],
           [1,2,3,4,5],
           [1,2,3,4,5],
           [4,5,6,7,8]]

    x.columns = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth']

    x = pd.DataFrame(data)

    x.groupby(list(x.columns)).size() > 1
```

The groupby function returns the desired dataframe output, while using

```
x[x.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

will still return duplicate rows. Is there a more pythonic way of only returning the unique duplicates?

Comment: @Ben.T x.drop_duplicates() will also return non-duplicate rows. I'm trying to only retain one row for each duplicate row.

Comment: @Ben.T good point! Thankyou! I'm new to Stack Overflow, not sure how to make your answer the correct one. Are you able to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain what you select already with `duplicated` and then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) such as:

```
print (x[x.duplicated()].drop_duplicates())
   first  second  third  fourth  fifth
1      1       2      3       4      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
x.drop_duplicates()
```

```
first   second  third   fourth  fifth
0   1   2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Comment: This still returns the non-duplicate row. Will edit question to show desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `.duplicated()` to check whether the row is a duplicate or not. If it is a duplicate, then it will return `True`.

After that, we create a flag, and then do a looping to get the duplicated row only. Check my code for details how I did it.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,3,4,5],
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [4,5,6,7,8]]

x = pd.DataFrame(data)
x.columns = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth']

lastFlag = False # create a flag for duplicated rows
dupl = x.duplicated() # check which row is a duplicate
for i in range(len(dupl)): # looping into the list
    # get the first duplicate and print it
    if lastFlag != dupl[i]:
        lastFlag = dupl[i]
        if dupl[i]:
            print(x.iloc[i, :]) # this print in pandas.Series type
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: cheers mate - works, but have a look at Ben T's answer, a bit more concise.

Comment: You're right. Sometimes, pandas have been done making the long algorithm in python to be lesser code.